# Странное поведение file_get_contents при вызове из класса и без класса

Tags: php

Суть проблемы такова: есть два php-скрипта. Оба делают одно и то же: парсят json-файл, который открывается как строка функцией **file_get_contents()**. Но есть одно отличие: первый скрипт написан в стиле ООП, а второй - в процедурном. Не знаю, влияет ли это на что-нибудь, но класс наотрез отказывается не то что парсить, открывать файл, тогда как рядом лежащий процедурный работает на ура. Открываю json, что в первом, что во втором случае, одинаково:

```
$file = file_get_contents( 'config.json' );
$json = json_decode( $file, true );
```

Бился с логами php и apache, ситуацию не прояснили. Класс проверял несколько раз, все нормально, кроме парсинга злосчастного файла.

З.Ы. В классе выше приведенный код располагается в конструкторе. Это не может влиять?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте указать полный путь до файла.

---

**UPD:** [Различие между абсолютными и относительными путями.](http://phpfaq.ru/paths)

Comment: Помогло, но можно ли обойтись без полного пути?

Comment: Попробуйте вначале вставить слеш.

Comment: Пробовал, результат отрицательный. И кстати, мне интересно, почему же такое разное поведение.

Comment: @DairoGrey возможно, что класс лежит в другой директории?